# Response 405 using Python Requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I try to send form data to the following url: https://peepoo.gq
I have tried adding headers, and almost everything in the chrome network log that a normal browser sends, but I am always left with error 405. My code:

```
import requests

url = 'https://peepoo.gq/'

payload = {'content' : 'bruh'}

headers = {
'accept' : 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
'user-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36',
'content-type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'accept-encoding' : 'gzip, deflate, br',
'accept-language' : 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
'cache-control' : 'max-age=0',
'content-length' : '12',
'dnt' : '1'
}

params = {'guestbook_name' : 'main'}

r = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers, params=params, allow_redirects=False)


print(r)
```

Comment: The website does not accept POST requests to that URL or there's a redirect involved converting your post to a GET.

Comment: @KlausD. how can I circumvent this? I think it may be a redirect issue. I've disabled redirects, but this doesn't work.

Comment: What do/don't you understand from that status?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code is working for me:

```
import requests

url = 'https://peepoo.gq/sign'

payload = {'content' : 'pickle rick'}

headers = {
'content-type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
}

params = {'guestbook_name' : 'main'}

r = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers, params=params, allow_redirects=True)
```

basically, you need to allow redirects and your `url` needs to point to `https://peepoo.gq/sign`

Comment: thank you for providing a solution! may I ask, how did you find the correct url to post to?

Comment: I just went to the website, opened the "developer tools" from chrome, navigated to the "network" tab, and then I posted a message. I noticed the url and also the redirects. :)

Comment: thank you! I was using the network log, but I must have missed that url. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You are using a POST method what is not accepted (said already by Klaus D.) and using the `data` parameter, what passes the information to the `POST` method also.

Apart from that you are passing twice the following key value pair: `'guestbook_name' : 'main'`
Once in the `url` and once in the `params`.

Answer (score 0):

I got 405 HTTP error, because of the default `User-Agent: python-requests/2.27.1` header that [requests](https://github.com/psf/requests) module sends . Changing **User-Agent** header helped me:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.75 Safari/537.36'
}
url = 'https://example.com/some-path'
data = {'a': 1}

r = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers, allow_redirects=True)
print(r.status_code)
```